# Java SE Error in cmd

Tags: java

I downloaded Java SE Development Kit 7u7 and then I tried to make a simple program in Notepad to see if it works.I wrote the program , saved it in notepad.

(Note: As I was saving I noticed that in the Save as type the java extension wasn't there, so I just added .java at the end of the name of my program)

For this java I tried using cmd but as far as I have understood, it doesn't find it. As error it says the first world of my first file i try to use "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Could there be a problem with my PC , the java or does this have to do with the fact that I used Notepad instead of Notepad++ wich I have heard is better than the simpler one?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the program before running?

Comment: It looks like java is not there in the classpath. Can you share the command used to compile the program?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Notepad saved your file as `YourProgram.java.txt`.

You need to enable "View extensions" to see the real extensions. Here a step-by-step guide how to enable: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-file-name-extensions.

> Open Folder Options by clicking the **Start** button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
>
> Click the View tab, and then, under Advanced settings, do one of the following:
>
> 1. To **display file extensions**, **clear** the Hide extensions for known file types check box, and then click OK.

Comment: yes but nothing works.It's like the cmd' main interest is that long error thing...i tried compileing it but the same error keeps appearing

Comment: and maybe it did save it as java.txt...i wouldn't be surprised as i have said in the note

Comment: I think you have to learn a lot. Did you try a tutorial for Java beginners?

Comment: not quite. I amin my first year in college and they started teaching us java using notepad. They gave us some notes and in class the programs work. But home on my PC is where i have problems

Comment: Of course, because the college has pre-configured PCs. You need to configure your own PC. Go look for a tutorial for beginner Java programmers. Here a link to the part "Getting started with Java": http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/getting-started-with-java. It is good practice to study other material than given by your college. Good luck!

Comment: FWIW I consider the teaching approach with Notepad misguided. The staff must decide whether their course is about programming or about basic system maintenance.

Comment: Good idea but it still doesn't see the extension.

Comment: Gah!... Follow the steps carefully to enable the extension! Then try again saving the file!

Comment: @nalply Better curse at the screen and not let it show through in comments :)

Comment: maybe the java program isn't working ? i folowed the stpes but still no results

Comment: or i should just try making the program in notepad++

Comment: @user1743007 Apart from opening a remote Desktop session with your computer, you can't be helped from the outside at this point. Thumbs up to your learning efforts, keep it up.

Comment: I flagged the question as too localized. We can't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Java source code files are not executable. You must compile it first using `javac` (this will produce a `MyClass.class` file) and then run using `java MyClass`. This is just the very basic information, there's actually a lot more to it, but I hope this will give you a starting point. You really should consult an online tutorial on the subject and **definitely** start working with a Java IDE such as Eclipse right away. Developing with Notepad is in fact much more involved, especially for a beginner, than with Eclipse.

Second, you have quite probably saved a file named `MyClass.java.txt`. Notepad adds the extension according to the chosen file type implicitly.

Comment: then why won't my computer find the java extension??? I realise i must have saved it in.txt but why won't it find the java extension?

Comment: You have a long, long way to go. It's not "your computer", it's just Notepad. Listen to the advice from other answerers and configure Windows to show full filenames.

Comment: This answer is valid, but this is the next step for you, I am afraid. Excactly as Marko said, you need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=58ZO_NaAOfU), it's about set up the java(JDK) path in windows 7!
and as advice for you, use Eclipse IDE or whatever you like to use!